Degree of correlation with categorical data
I have a student conducting an experiment. She has data on different emotions, mapped to different sounds by different participants so we wan't to test the degree of correlation between different participants mathing of emotions to sounds.
From researching around the topic it seems Fleiss' Kappa seems an appropriate measure, and I just wanted to check with a statistician whether there is a more appropriate measure, or any other issue I've missed.
Partipant 1     - Sound 1 - Happy Sound 2 - Sad Sound 3 - Suprised ...
Participant 2   -  Sound 1 - Happy Sound 2 - Sad Sound 3 - Suprised ..
Participant 3    - Sound 1 - Sad Sound 2 -Happy Sound 3 - Suprised ..

Does this help?

If you want to evaluate inter-rater reliability, then yes, Fleiss is an appropriate tool. It will tell you that your subjects agree beyond "chance". It is better than Cohen in your case, isince you have mnore than 2 subjects.  But if you wanted to know if some sounds are generally more associated with specific emotions,  a contingency table, and test, would work better.
